# paypal plus modul to magento 2 SSH InvalidArgumentException

Tags: magento2, third-party-module, ssh, paypal-plus

I have a problem with intergration of Paypal Plus Modul for Magento 2.
I found this module on github

> https://github.com/i-ways/magento2-paypal-plus

There are instructions not to install it on Magento 2 but I got stuck at the point with 
`Run the command composer require iways/module-pay-pal-plus from instructions.`
I get in my SSH Console:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
Could not find a matching version of package iways/module-pay-pal-plus.
Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable).
```

I write in composer.json:

```
"repositories": {
"0": {
"type": "composer",
"url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
},
"1": {
"url": "git@github.com:i-ways/magento2-paypal-plus.git",
"type": "git"
},
"swissuplabs": {
"type": "composer",
"url": "https://ci.swissuplabs.com/api/packages.json"
}
},
```

please help, what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Following the install instructions at the [PayPal Plus extension repository on GitHub](https://github.com/i-ways/magento2-paypal-plus) install the plugin as follows:

1. Make sure that there are no code snippets from previous installation attempts in your *composer.json*.
2. Add the extensions repository to the end of your *composer.json*:

```
{
    "repositories": [
            {
                "url": "git@github.com:i-ways/magento2-paypal-plus.git",
                "type": "git"
            }
        ]
}
```

3. Save the changes to your *composer.json* file.
4. To install the extension via composer, execute the command
   `composer require iways/module-pay-pal-plus` from the command line.
   (Alternatively you can install the extension by adding the following line to your *composer.json*: `"require": { "iways/module-pay-pal-plus": "~1.0" }`)
   I recommend the method from 4. because it is not as error prone as editing the *composer.json* file by hand.
5. After the extension is installed you can now activate it via the command line. To do so, go to the root directory of your Magento 2 instance and execute the following command:
   `bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content Iways_PayPalPlus`
6. To initialize the Database updates you must run following command afterwards:
   `bin/magento setup:upgrade`
7. Static files may have to be generated and/or renewed. Execute this command:
   `bin/magento setup:di:compile`